# Android: Bitmap config ARGB_8888 not working on some devices

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have the following code in my app. Here I am basically greying a bitmap. The  bitmap blurred is obtained by blurring an image.

```
    final Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(blurred.getWidth(), blurred.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    final Canvas c = new Canvas(resultBitmap);

    c.drawBitmap(blurred, 0, 0, null);

    final Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAlpha(127);

    c.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(linearLayout.getWidth(), linearLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565), 0, 0, p);
    BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resultBitmap);
    linearLayout.setBackground(background);
```

This code is working as expected on all devices but on Micromax E313 I don't get the desired result. After some debugging I see that the issue is the use of ARGB_8888 in the line

```
final Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(blurred.getWidth(), blurred.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Now using `RGB_565` the problem solves but the resulting bitmap doesn't look as good as it looks with `ARGB_8888`.

My question is is that is their a way to get ARGB_8888 to work on such devices. If not is there a way to check whether `ARGB_8888` is supported so that I can fall back to `RGB_565` on such devices. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Because **ARGB_8888** use **4 bytes** (32 bit) for color so that may be some device with **Android** version level small will not work.

You can check resultBitmap is null or not to use RGB_565 then.